# Does instruction which control unit fetch contain both what to do and where to do (in which unit of processor)?

Tags: computer-architecture

What instruction really means? I am facing problem in understanding it. If the instruction is to copy this and create a new file and place there so it seems it d doesn't need processing so what will control unit do?

Answer (score 1):

In *computer architecture* (the current tag, but I wonder if it is really adapted), an instruction is whatever the computer architect decide to be.  It is the most basic bit string having a independent meaning.  Some instructions may be quite simple (add two registers and put the result in the first one), some may be strange (provide the most significant bits of a constant value used in the next instruction) and the boundary between being one instruction or several may be not that clear (you could consider the previous example and the instruction which follow it as a single instruction).

I don't know any processor which provides instructions like the one you are describing.  Those seems to me to be at the abstraction level of an operating system, not of a processor architecture.  It could be that mainframes provide such instruction (in the channel control part), but even there my guess is that it would need to be the combination of several more basic instructions.  That guess holds also for operating system.